# Function to create list containing elements in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

QUESTION: How to write a function that creates a list containing 3 elements and prints with separating each line?

My solution so far:

```
def takes_list(list):
    for item in list:
        print(item)


takes_list(['I', 'Like', 'Eating'])
```

How can I create the list without using a hard-coded list?

Comment: have  you googled it? what about `print("\n".join(['I', 'like', 'eating']))`?

Comment: what is your expected input/output ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sep='\n'`.

```
print(*list,sep='\n')
```

Avoid using keywords and built-ins as your variable names. If you want use `list` as your variable name then use `_list` or `list_`.

If you have a string and you want to create a list of words from the string then take look at [EMiDU](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5612001/emidu)'s answer.

```
def func(_str):
    print(*_str.split(),sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need a function which gets string and prints words in separate lines, here you go:

```
def print_words(text):
    for item in text.split():
        print(item)

>>> print_words('I Like Eating')
I
Like
Eating
```

Comment: thanks although I need it to not be hard coded

Comment: It is not hard coded. Look at first 3 lines - it is function converting `text` string to list and printing each word in one line.

Answer (score 1):

if I understood correctly you want to pass to a function a bunch of strings that should be printed on a separate line, so here is my approach:

```
def takes_list(*args):
    print(*args, sep='\n')


takes_list('I', 'Like', 'Eating')
```

**output:**

```
I
Like
Eating
```

in this case, you can use directly the `print` build-in function:

```
print('I', 'Like', 'Eating', sep='\n')
```